# Publishing package with gradle in a nexus repository with self-signed certificate

Tags: android-studio, maven, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to publish to a nexus repository (which has a self-signed certificate) using gradle in android studio. I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException:
Could not GET 'https://server-domain/repository/maven-snapshots/...'. Received status code 503 from server: Service Unavailable
```

I was getting the same error when tried with maven deploy but I after adding the self-signed certificate to trusted certificates in java keystore (cacerts), I am now able to publish with maven but still cannot publish using gradle.

I have checked and assured that gradle is referring to the same java jdk version I use for maven.
Can anyone help if I need to check anything else or be aware of any differences?

I am using the following code to publish with gradle:

```
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId libraryGroupId
            version libraryVersion
            artifactId libraryArtifactId
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${artifactId}-release.aar")
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            name "maven-snapshots"
            url "https://server-domain/repository/maven-snapshots/"
            credentials {
                username "username"
                password "pass"
            }}
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is located here: `Received status code 503 from server: Service Unavailable` your service for the repository does not work...

Comment: How do you mean? It works with maven. I am able to publish packages with mvn deploy